# Add class to parent div and then remove it

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel, slick.js

I am using slick slider to create a home page slider with 4 images. The first image is unique and I need the background image to change. I am currently using the ::before and ::after for my css changes. I can get the first slide when active to add the class to the parent div, however once it switches to the next slide, it wont remove the added class.

See below:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item mega-slide">
        <div class="carousel-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/home-mega-volume.jpg');"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="item" >
        <div class="carousel-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/slide1.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" >
        <div class="carousel-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/slide2.jpg');"></div>
    </div>      
    <div class="item" >
        <div class="carousel-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/slide3.jpg');"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.carousel-inner').slick({
dots: false,
autoplay: true,
arrows: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 1000,
slidesToShow: 1,
adaptiveHeight: true,
fade:true,
asNavFor: '.carousel-text',
cssEase:"linear"
});
  if ( $(".mega-slide").hasClass("slick-active") ) {
   $(".carousel-bg").addClass("remove");
  }
  else ($(".carousel-bg").removeClass("remove"));
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: I think what you're wanting to do is hook into the `beforeChange` or `afterChange` event of the slickSlider.  See the slickslider docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested working fine. Hope this help you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.carousel-inner').slick({
  dots: true,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 5000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  slide: '.item',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});

$('.carousel-inner').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $('.carousel-inner').removeClass('addedactive');
    if(currentSlide == 0){
        $('.carousel-inner').addClass('addedactive');
    }
});

});
```